# Android flash restart. OnDestroy called before/while OnResume

Tags: android

I have numerous crashreports that only can occur under the condition, that `OnDestroy` is called before or while `OnResume` is executed.

In this case I initialize the class with the context. I have crashreport with `null reference exception` in `getDefaultSharedPreferences` which can only occur when `this.context` is null. `this.context` is null only when CalledByOnDestroy was executed.

How can this be?

```
   public public class ImageProcessor {

        private Context context;

        // called by OnCreate
        public ImageProcessor(Context context) {
             this.context = context;
        }

        public void OnDestroyHandler() {
            this.context = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void OnResumeHandler() {
            this.frameId = 0;
            SharedPreferences defaultSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show more code. Either the full class, or the essential lifecycle methods if the class is very large.

Comment: The recreated activity (e.g. rotation) can under some circumstances be started before the dying one is completely finished. You can't stop that from happening so you have to work around it somehow.

Comment: I do not allow rotation. Orientation is fixed to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

In `OnResumeHandler` you can check if this.context == null , if is not then get the defaultSharedPreferences

Comment: That is not the problem. I just would like to rely on the fact, that an app is started before it is destroyed. This behavior does not make any sense. Imo it is a fundamental bug in Android.